Docker containerized application not able to connect
I am using a spring cloud config server to externalize the configuration properties for my project
For this purpose I have created these microservices

configserver
accounts
cards
loans
Rabbit Mq image from dockerhub downloaded in local

when I am trying to create and start the containers using the docker compose up file, I am getting below exception
024-06-14 08:59:34 2024-06-14T03:29:34.350Z  WARN 1 --- [cards] [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Could not locate PropertySource ([ConfigServerConfigDataResource@473b3b7a uris = array['http://localhost:8071/'], optional = true, profiles = 'default']): I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8071/accounts/default": Connection refused.
Please note the configserver and rabbitmq both are getting started but account,loans and cards are getting exited due to the same error.
Also If I use the configserver as a container and start the loans,cards or accounts ms directly from IDE i am able to connect.
application.yaml for configserver:
    spring:
     application:
      name: configserver
     profiles:
      #active: native
      active: git
     cloud:
      config:
       server:
        #native:
         #search-locations: "classpath:/config"
         #search-locations: "file:///D:/code/elearn_eazybank/section6/config-filepath"
        git:
         uri: "actual URL removed due to confidentaility"
         default-label: main
         timeout: 5 
         clone-on-start: true
         force-pull: true
         
    management:
     endpoints:
      web:
       exposure:
        include: "*"
     health:
      readiness-state: 
       enabled: true
      liveness-state:
       enabled: true
     endpoint:
      health:
       probes:
        enabled: true
         
         
         
    encypt:
     key: "45D81EC1EF61DF9AD8D3E5BB397F9"
      
    server:
     port: 8071
     
     
    

application.yaml for accounts:
    server:
      port: 8080
    logging:
     level:
      org:
       springframework:
        web: "DEBUG"
    spring:
      application:
        name: "accounts"
      profiles:
        active: "prod"
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        username: sa
        password: ''
      h2:
        console:
          enabled: true
      jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: update
        show-sql: true
      config:
        import: "configserver:http://localhost:8071/"
        
      rabbitmq:
      host: localhost
      port: 5672
      username: guest
      password: guest
        
    management:
     endpoints:
      web:
       exposure:
        include: "*"
        
     

docker-compose.yaml:
    services:
      rabbit:
        image: rabbitmq:3.13-management
        hostname: rabbitmq
        ports:
          - "5672:5672"
          - "15672:15672"
        healthcheck:
          test: rabbitmq-diagnostics check_port_connectivity
          interval: 10s
          timeout: 5s
          retries: 10
          start_period: 5s
        extends:
          file: common-config.yaml
          service: network-deploy-service
    
      configserver:
        image: "dockerhub image name"
        container_name: configserver-ms
        ports:
          - "8071:8071"
        depends_on:
          rabbit:
            condition: service_healthy
        healthcheck:
          test: "curl --fail --silent localhost:8071/actuator/health/readiness | grep UP || exit 1"
          interval: 10s
          timeout: 5s
          retries: 10
          start_period: 10s
        extends:
          file: common-config.yaml
          service: microservice-base-config
    
      accounts:
        image: "dockerhub image name"
        container_name: accounts-ms
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
        depends_on:
          configserver:
            condition: service_healthy
        environment:
          SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME: "accounts"
        extends:
          file: common-config.yaml
          service: microservice-configserver-config
    
      loans:
        image: "dockerhub image name"
        container_name: loans-ms
        ports:
          - "8090:8090"
        depends_on:
          configserver:
            condition: service_healthy
        environment:
          SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME: "loans"
        extends:
          file: common-config.yaml
          service: microservice-configserver-config
    
      cards:
        image: "dockerhub image name"
        container_name: cards-ms
        ports:
          - "9000:9000"
        depends_on:
          configserver:
            condition: service_healthy
        environment:
          SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME: "cards"
        extends:
          file: common-config.yaml
          service: microservice-configserver-config
    
    networks:
      eazybank:
        driver: "bridge"
    

common-config.yaml:
    services:
      network-deploy-service:
        networks:
          - eazybank
    
      microservice-base-config:
        extends:
          service: network-deploy-service
        deploy:
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 700m
        environment:
          SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: "rabbit"
    
      microservice-configserver-config:
        extends:
          service: microservice-base-config
        environment:
          SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: default
          SPRING_CONFIG_IMPORT: configserver:http://configserver:8071/

Tried to modify the networks attribute, but nothing worked

seems services trying to connect to localhost instead of configserver. verify if you have configured localhost somewhere

That import: "configserver:http://localhost:8071/" in the "application.yml for accounts" seems to be it.
